# Log headers & contents of rejected messages via Postfix

Tags: postfix

I'd like to save the details (headers and contents) of all messages that are rejected when sent out from our server, so I can figure out why they might have been rejected.

Is there any way for postfix to save a message somewhere when it has been rejected?

Forwarding a copy to the root mail account would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `bounce` to your [`notify_classes` directive](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes) in `main.cf`. This will send a copy of all of the message headers to postmaster. (For privacy reasons, Postfix truncates the message body on the copy sent to postmaster.)

Comment: sorry to revive this but is there a way to stop Postfix from truncating the message body when sending a copy to postmaster?