# postfix removing body of bounced messages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

I've noticed for messages that fail to deliver with postfix, the body of the message is removed. Here's an example (real emails replaced with temps):

```
--5F54EFCA0A.1653443634/MYDOMAIN.COM
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; MYDOMAIN.COM
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 5F54EFCA0A
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; FROM@MYDOMAIN.COM
Arrival-Date: Wed, 25 May 2022 01:47:13 +0000 (UTC)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; TO@GMAIL.COM
Original-Recipient: rfc822;TO@GMAIL.COM
Action: delayed
Status: 4.2.1
Remote-MTA: dns; alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 450-4.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is
    receiving mail at a rate that 450-4.2.1 prevents additional messages from
    being delivered. Please resend your 450-4.2.1 message at a later time. If
    the user is able to receive mail at that 450-4.2.1 time, your message will
    be delivered. For more information, please 450-4.2.1 visit 450 4.2.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ReceivingRate
    i9-20020a544089000000b0032b06b69e67si10079646oii.275 - gsmtp
Will-Retry-Until: Mon, 30 May 2022 01:47:13 +0000 (UTC)

--5F54EFCA0A.1653443634/MYDOMAIN.COM
Content-Description: Undelivered Message Headers
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Return-Path: <FROM@MYDOMAIN.COM>
Received: from [XX.XX.XX.XX] (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by MYDOMAIN.COM (Postfix) with ESMTP id 5F54EFCA0A
    for <TO@GMAIL.COM>; Wed, 25 May 2022 01:47:13 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============9070788644322080819=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: MY SUBJECT
From: FROM@MYDOMAIN.COM
To: TO@GMAIL.COM
Message-Id: <20220525014713.5F54EFCA0A@MYDOMAIN.COM>
Date: Wed, 25 May 2022 01:47:13 +0000 (UTC)

--5F54EFCA0A.1653443634/MYDOMAIN.COM--
*** HEADER EXTRACTED deferred/3/3E377FD67F ***
named_attribute: encoding=8bit
*** MESSAGE FILE END deferred/3/3E377FD67F ***
```

I'm wondering are any of the below options possible? Just trying to find a way to avoid losing the original message whenever there's a bounce.

1. Is there a way to stop postfix from generating this message and instead just place the original message in the deferred queue?
2. Or, can I change how quickly it removes the original message and replaces it with this one?
3. Or, is there a way to customize the format to make sure the original message's body content is included?

Comment: Are you possibly also having a problem with your mail client? The sample you quoted.. should be accompanied by an explanatory message. Did your mail client fail to display that?

Answer (score 1):

That message is not necessarily undeliverable, just undelivered. It was not accepted by Google *yet*. It might be, as stated, "at a later time". I think the confusion stems from *"bounce"* being generally understood as *"undeliverable, returned in full"*.

But **this sample is just a notification about a *delay***, as seen in the subject and `Action: delayed`. These notifications deliberately only *reference* the original message: it would additionally later be returned in full if and when it is *permanently* rejected, or if it is still not delivered at the time specified in `Will-Retry-Until`.

> Just trying to find a way to avoid losing the original message
> whenever there's a bounce.

The message is *not* lost.

1. Postfix *has* queued this message, as is, including the body. The code provided with `X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 5F54EFCA0A` is the name of the queue file. Using the [`postcat(1)`](https://www.postfix.org/postcat.1.html) command the admin can be retrieve it, including the body - until delivery or return.
2. You can configure [`delay_warning_time`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#delay_warning_time) to warn about delays at a later time (or not at all). Do *not* disable this feature if you have users who do understand and make use of delay notifications.
3. Your can configure [`maximal_queue_lifetime`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#maximal_queue_lifetime) to define how long postfix should attempt to retry delivery when faced it temporary errors. I do *not* recommend to change this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried your suggestion using `postcat -q 5F54EFCA0A` but it said it doesn't exist. I believe that only works with the Message ID, not the Queue ID. Is there another way to use postcat that can look up via Queue ID and retrieve the body? And I'm aware of your suggestions with 2 and 3, but really my desire isn't to delay or change the liftetime, it's moreso to change postfix's behavior of queueing the message *as is*, rather than this bounce message otherwise I worry the body can't be retrieved. Please tell me there's hope :)

Comment: It won't be in the queue if it has been delivered meanwhile ;) Find the queue ID in your logs, that will tell you what happened before you checked.

Comment: @smaili Postfix *does* queue the complete message, and it *can* be retrieved from the queue - until there is no longer a need to, because delivery or return has happened.

Comment: I want to believe it but I've tried everything and have gotten nowhere, including a full grep on the entire OS but nothing. I also did stumble on this: https://serverfault.com/questions/491224/log-headers-contents-of-rejected-messages-via-postfix where it is mentioned that postmaster does truncate the body of bounced messages so at this point I don't think it's possible to retrieve.

Comment: @smaili Just `grep` alone will not work on certain binary log file storage. E.g. for systemd journal, you want to use `journalctl` to view logs. The notifications for the `postmaster` mailbox are separate from the notification to the sender. Truncation in those happens in the same manner, but for different reasons.